# Extrapolation using Taylor series - giving negative results for increasing positive inputs

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, interpolation, extrapolation

I would like to use a 2nd order Taylor series expansion to perform an extrapolation to predict points outside of a known range. I am using the following formulation:

\begin{equation*}
 d(N+ \Delta N) = d\bigr|_{@N} + 
 \Delta N \frac{\partial d}{\partial N}\Bigr|_{@N}  +
 \frac{(\Delta N)^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 d}{\partial N^2}\Bigr|_{@N} 
 \end{equation*}

where, d is an increasing function ($d_N > d_{N-1} > d_{N-2}$) and the differentials are discretized as follows:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial d}{\partial N}\Bigr|_N &= d_N - d_{N-1}\\\\
\frac{\partial^2 d}{\partial N^2}\Bigr|_N &= 
\frac{\partial d}{\partial N}\Bigr|_N - \frac{\partial d}{\partial N}\Bigr|_{N-1}   \\ \\
&= (d_N - d_{N-1}) - (d_{N-1} - d_{N-2}) \\
&= d_N - 2 d_{N-1} + d_{N-2} 
\end{align*}
Hence the extrapolation equation is reduced to:
\begin{equation*}
d_{N+\Delta N} = d_N + \Delta N (d_N - d_{N-1}) + 
\frac{(\Delta N)^2}{2}(d_N - 2 d_{N-1} + d_{N-2})
\end{equation*}

**My question is,** for all positive and increasing values of d, is it possible that the extrapolated value $d_{N+\Delta N}$ could be less than $d_N$ or even worse, negative?

Consider the following example where,
\begin{align*}
 d_{N-2} &= 0.3737 &\\
 d_{N-1} &= 0.5185 &\\
 d_N &= 0.6153 & \\
 \Delta N &= 10
\end{align*}

It can be seen that the slope from $d_{N-2}$ to $d_{N-1}$ and $d_{N-1}$ to $d_{N}$ are both positive. But after extrapolation using the above equation, I get a value $ {d_{N+ \Delta N} = -0.8167}$.

I understand that $d_{N-1}$ is closer to $d_{N}$ than $d_{N-2}$. But still, since the inputs are all increasing and positive, why is the Taylor expansion giving a negative value? I am failing to find an explanation to this. If not for a fix or a correction, it would be really helpful if someone could atleast comment on this and help me understand why this is happening. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Many thanks! Cheers!

P.S. I cannot use higher order terms in the approximation since the extrapolation is part of a bigger implementation and using higher order terms would complicate things a lot.

**Edit 1**

In my problem, d is a strictly non decreasing function in [0,1]. A negative value for $d$ doesnt make physical sense.

I am looking for an extrapolation scheme using 3 past values ($d_N, d_{N-1}, d_{N-2}$) (hence with quadratic terms). **What would be one of the better schemes that I can use to give me positive extrapolated values with larger $\Delta N$'s?**

Using a first order Taylor expansion gave higher error in the predicted value. And using higher order terms than 2nd order would be difficult with the already existing solution methodology that I have. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hello Aravind, although someone has already answered as to why your approximation is not working, could you share more of problem, so that we may find a way to fix the approximation?

Comment: Hey Carlos, thanks for your comment. I have added an edit with some more info below my original post. Please let me know if there is any more details that I could provide that would make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $d_N - 2d_{N-1} + d_{N-2}$ is negative, so your approximation is a quadratic function with a $\cap$-shape. As with any Taylor approximation, the approximation is good near the reference point (i.e. $\Delta N$ near zero) and worsens as you get farther away. Note that in this particular case (where you know your function is increasing), a quadratic is particularly bad because no quadratic is globally increasing. (It may be a good local approximation though.)

You can check that when $\Delta N$ is small, you see an increase due to the positive slope. But when $\Delta N$ is large, the quadratic tends to negative infinity, so you will always see smaller values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Was really helpful in understanding the problem better. Could you suggest an extrapolation scheme that would fit here and I could use with considerable Delta_N's without predicting negative values? I have also added an edit to my original post. Maybe you could check that as well and let me know if there are more information that I could provide. Many thanks!

Comment: @Aravind Given that you only have three values, you might be better off with some sort of linear regression: since the three values are increasing, the resulting line will definitely be increasing, which fits your model assumptions. Note however that no matter what method you use, it is dangerous to extrapolate far from the data you have at hand.

Comment: Thankyou! I ll try using that.